# Class implementing interface should be able to only add an object of the same class

Tags: java, generics

Let's say I have an interface in Java:

```
interface I {
    void add(I foo);
}
```

, and also two classes C and D that implement this interface.

Is there any way I can modify **the interface** such that I could only do:

```
C c = new C();
c.add(new C());
```

, but not

```
c.add(new D());
```

?

I had this question on an exam, but my only idea was to use the *instanceof* operator in the definition of the method:

```
class C implements I {
    public void add(I foo) {
        if (foo instanceof C) {
            System.out.println("instance of C");
        } else {
            System.out.println("another instance");
        }
    }
}
```

However, I don't know how to modify the interface such that I produce the same effect.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes - you need generics:

```
interface I <T extends I<T>> {
    void add(T foo);
}
```

To define a class to use it, code it like this:

```
class C implements I<C> {
    @Override
    public void add(C foo) {
        //
    }
}
```

Note that there is no way to prevent the implementer from coding this (assuming `D` also implements `I`):

```
class C implements I<D> {
    @Override
    public void add(D foo) {
        //
    }
}
```

However, this would only be a problem if the coder of class `C` knew of the existence of class `D` and chose to use it, which is unlikely if they are focused on coding class `C`.

Even given this caveat, if I was setting this exam question, I would expect the above to be the answer.

Comment: This method is not fool-proof. For instance, you can still do something like `class D implements I<C>`. However, it is a very strong indicator of intent, and a dev violating the above deserves whatever they get.

Comment: To avoid warning about unparameterized type, the declaration should be `interface I <T extends I<T>> `.

Comment: @JimGarrison Thanks - Can't believe I missed that... :( I've edited the answer.

Comment: There's really no point to the tighter bounds. With the `C` defined as above, you can still do `class D implements I<C>`

Comment: @newacct Oh crap, so you can. Thanks - I'll edit this later when I have time.

Comment: @JimGarrison Actually, your suggestion doesn't help after all.

Comment: @Bohemian It only prevents the warning.  You can subvert it if you can make new implementations of `I`, but a _user_ of the original `C implements I<C>` and `D implements I<D>` get type-safe `add()` methods.  In that scenario you can't code `C c = new C(); D d = new D(); c.add(d);`  I.e. if the user's playing in your sandbox you can protect them somewhat; if they make their own sandbox (new implementations) they're on their own :-)

Comment: @JimGarrison I like it! I've further refined the answer a bit. Thanks for your input.